# RMSE, MAE and MAPE reduced but RMSPE increased after removing outliers in linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, regression

I am using a linear regression model with 465 datapoints to predict crop yield of wheat. The data points are spilt into training and testing sets in 80:20 ratio. Initially, I tried linear regression without removing the outliers. This is the result I got -

```
{'mae': 872.8597882968111,
 'mse': 1416762.85492493655,
 'rmse': 1190.6374501221957,
 'r2': -1.5692174949248995,
 'rmspe': 60.74858353588904,
 'mape': 43.157895501073469}
```

Later, when I box-plotted, I found outliers. Using inter-quartile range method, I removed 2 outliers and applied the linear regression. This is the result I got -

```
{'mae': 477.5228119968111,
 'mse': 383950.56959393655,
 'rmse': 619.6374501221957,
 'r2': 0.3955174949248933,
 'rmspe': 139.71598353588516,
 'mape': 35.944895501073276}
```

RMSE, MAE, MAPE reduced after removing outliers, but RMSPE increased. Shouldn't RMSPE also reduce? Did something go wrong?
I am calculating RMSPE as `rmspe = (np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)))) * 100`

Comment: np.mean will calculate the mean of the squares of error. why to divide the mean again by n?

Comment: i am using code similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165807/how-to-calculate-rmspe-in-python-using-numpy)

Comment: Is this train error or test error?

Comment: @Tim test error

Comment: Did you remove samples from test set as well, or only train set?